# How to reference parent value from child value within same column in SQL using select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where parent id is referencing to null but child id is referencing to parent id within the same column of a table? How to use select query to get which child values referencing to which parent values?

For example: billno  Pref

```
    |      bill no        |         ref      |
    +---------------------+------------------+
    |          1          |                  |
    |          2          |         1        |
    |          3          |                  |
    |          4          |         3        |
    |          5          |         3        |
```

Comment: post your sample data and expected output in proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join on the same table. Try below query.

select a.billno, a.ref from PREF a INNER JOIN PREF b ON a.billno = b.ref;

Answer (score 0):

you need commonId in both of them
for join
Only the ones that exist:

```
Select table1.billno, table2.ref
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.CommonID=table2.CommonID
```

There are only the first ones(table1):

```
Select table1.billno, table2.ref
from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.CommonID=table2.CommonID
```

There are only the first ones(table2):

```
Select table1.billno, table2.ref
from table1 Right outer join table2 on table1.CommonID=table2.CommonID
```

There are exist on the both of them:

```
Select table1.billno, table2.ref
from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.CommonID=table2.CommonID
```